# Kong Ingress Controller on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kong, kong-ingress

I'm trying to deploy Kong Ingress Controller into my K8s cluster deployed using kubeadm in virtualbox.

It's composed of a master and two worker nodes.

According to the documentation, I'm using a DBless deploy:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/master/deploy/single/all-in-one-dbless.yaml
```

The result is this:

```
namespace/kong created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/kongclusterplugins.configuration.konghq.com created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/kongconsumers.configuration.konghq.com created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/kongingresses.configuration.konghq.com created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/kongplugins.configuration.konghq.com created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/tcpingresses.configuration.konghq.com created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/udpingresses.configuration.konghq.com created
serviceaccount/kong-serviceaccount created
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kong-leader-election created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kong-ingress created
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kong-leader-election created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kong-ingress created
service/kong-proxy created
service/kong-validation-webhook created
deployment.apps/ingress-kong created
```

So far, so good. Here are the components it creates:

```
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE
pod/ingress-kong-7498964bb6-ddbfw   2/2     Running   2 (7m37s ago)   7m41s

NAME                              TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
service/kong-proxy                LoadBalancer   10.110.24.254   <pending>     80:31345/TCP,443:31076/TCP   7m41s
service/kong-validation-webhook   ClusterIP      10.108.43.162   <none>        443/TCP                      7m41s

NAME                           READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/ingress-kong   1/1     1            1           7m41s

NAME                                      DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/ingress-kong-7498964bb6   1         1         1       7m41s
```

I'm exposing the loadbalancer using port-forward:

```
kubectl port-forward svc/kong-proxy -n kong 80:80
```

Then I curl http://localhost the result is as expected:

```
curl : {"message":"no Route matched with those values"}
```

And finally, I deploy a set of ingress rules to test it:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx:alpine
        name: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources: {}
status: {}
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: httpd
  name: httpd
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: httpd
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: httpd
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: httpd:alpine
        name: httpd
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources: {}
status: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: nginx
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: httpd
  name: httpd-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: httpd
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    konghq.com/strip-path: "true"
  name: nginx-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: kong
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /nginx
        pathType: Prefix
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    konghq.com/strip-path: "true"
  name: httpd-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: kong
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: httpd-service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /httpd
        pathType: Prefix
```

When I try to curl any path defined in my ingress rules, for instance, **curl http://localhost/httpd** it throws this error:

```
curl : An invalid response was received from the upstream server
```

The logs from the kong proxy shows this error:

```
[error] 1097#0: *6474 connect() failed (113: Host is unreachable) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: kong, request: "GET /httpd HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.88.0.58:80/", host: "localhost"
```

The IP shows when I list the endpoints:

```
httpd-service   10.88.0.58:80       14m
nginx-service   10.88.0.59:80       14m
```

Both services (httpd-service and nginx-service) are correct and I'm able to access them when I port forward their service to my local machine.

I did the same deploy into another cluster on DigitalOcean and besides provisioning a loadbalacer, the result was pretty much the same.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks!

Comment: I just followed your question step by step and everything worked. I used GCP Kubernetes cluster.

Comment: For some unknown reason, I've got it working in DigitalOcean.
But my local cluster still has the same problem I reported above.
I don't know if it's due to the fact it can't allocate a load balancer and an external IP.

I don't think it's the reason for the error.

I will reset my cluster and try again locally.

Just for the record I used kong ingress controller version 2.0.7

Comment: What do you use for local cluster?

Comment: In order to train for the CKA I used virtualbox to create 3 ubuntu VMs. I used containerd as container runtime and Kubeadm to bootstrap the cluster.  I'm running k8s version 1.23.2 in this cluster.

Comment: Could you try the latest version of Kong Ingress Controller?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of **Internal Load balancer IP** in which kong-proxy is installed.

Your getting **curl : {"message":"no Route matched with those values"}** after port forwarding is because URL hit internally.

When you created ingress **httpd** service which is hosted remotely. Using the internal load balancer we cannot able to reach the external hosted domain.

So try installing kong ingress as **external load balancer IP** which is exposed to outside network. So that you can access the hosted service.

Get the installation yaml for kong which has external load balancer in it.